# Why is Edge loading a smaller image than requested?

Tags: html, image, srcset

If you view the snippet (Full Page) on a screen 1200px or wider then the 4 pictures are 255px wide.

Relevant sizes attribute:

```
sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw"
```

Relevant srcset attribute:

```
srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w,     
  https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w,     
  https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, 
  https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, 
  https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, 
  https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w"
```

On Chrome the image that is loaded is 540 by 540px as this is the smallest one that is larger than 255px. However Edge loads a 150px by 150px image which is then scaled up to 255px and looks blurry.

Why does Edge choose this image? Is it merely because 150 is closer to 255 than 540 is? Is there anyway of making it choose the 540 one?

```css
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <picture><source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw"><source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x405.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x576.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x744.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x900.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1440.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 510px, 100vw"><img srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg" width="1920" height="1920"></picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <picture><source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw"><source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x405.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x576.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x744.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x900.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1440.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 510px, 100vw"><img srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg" width="1920" height="1920"></picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <picture><source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw"><source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x405.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x576.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x744.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x900.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1440.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 510px, 100vw"><img srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg" width="1920" height="1920"></picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <picture><source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw"><source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x405.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x576.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x744.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x900.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1440.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 510px, 100vw"><img srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/540x540.jpg 540w, https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg 150w, https://via.placeholder.com/768x768.jpg 768w, https://via.placeholder.com/992x992.jpg 992w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200.jpg 1200w, https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg 1920w" sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 255px, 25vw" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1920.jpg" width="1920" height="1920"></picture>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could this be because you have zooomed in or out by accident?

Comment: I can confirm that zoom is normal/100%.